# AB Testing / Experimentation: ratio estimator based on parameter estimates of a regression model

Tags: regression, causality, ab-test

Assume we run an experiment / AB test, hence we have a treatment $D$, exogenous covariates $X$ and outcome variable $Y$.

A standard regression estimator then identifies the treatment effect $\tau$ as a *difference of means*:

$$
    E[Y|X, D = 1] - E[Y|X, D = 0]  = \tau.
$$

In AB testing instead, the object of interest if often a ratio estimator

$$
  \frac{E[Y|X, D = 1]}{E[Y|X, D = 0]} -1
$$

which can be interpreted as the performance change of the treatment in per cent.

Is there a way to compute such a ratio estimator based on estimates from a standard regression routine (e.g. output`lm()` in R, or `reg` in Stata) and without making any additional distributional assumptions?

One solution would be to run a log-regression, e.g. `lm(log(Y) ~ X + D)`, which should approximate the ratio estimator for "small enough" effects. But using logs is of course unattractive if $Y$ contains many zeros.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Poisson regression? https://bookdown.org/roback/bookdown-BeyondMLR/ch-poissonreg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fitting the model, you can simply make two predictions of the conditional mean, one for $D=1$ and one for $D=0$ and take their ratio:

$$\frac{\hat{E}[Y|X,D=1]}{\hat{E}[Y|X,D=0]}-1$$

**But note** that this ratio depends on the values of $X$, different from the additive effect estimate. And of course it does: You are running a linear additive model to estimtate the treatment effect. This is different from the log-model you mentioned, which is in essence a multiplicative model. Here, the effect of $D$ in terms of percentage is constant over all values of $X$.

So you can only estimate a marginal effect of the treatment in terms of percentage increase for a particular $X$, which you should choose wisely for the substantive question at hand.

Note that to get an estimate of the uncertainty for the estimated effect on the ratio scale, you will also need the standard error of both point predictions.

Comment: Thanks for this very good answer. I was thinking along very similar lines, so it's good to see my intuition validated :)